# Printer Port configuration using redmon and ghostscript, error invalid window handle

Tags: printing, ghostscript, postscript, redmon

I want to print to pdf using Redmon and Ghostscript on windows 10, for which i added a new printer(set drivers to ghostpdf.inf) and added redirection port(RPT1). Now when i configure this port i get the error Invalid window handle, please check the picture. Thanks[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay you need admin rights -
edit port configuration using cmd as admin with command -
printui.dll PrintUIEntry /p /n "printer name"

Answer (score 0):

It is much better and more stable if you create a new port via "Print Management" of Windows, not via Printer Properties window

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, late to the party, but I tried using Win11.
And for me,  as @Jay mentioned, run cmd as administrator and then

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /n /p "Ghostscript PDF PRINTER"
```

helped. Than my program was called when Printing to "Ghostscript PDF PRINTER" with redmon 1.9.
Very nice.